# How to Delete cache and app dir in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app,  I store some images in cache directory and some files in application document directory,  now I want to add possibility to my users to delete the cache dir and app dir, 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package

Then try this code:

```
  Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
    final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
      cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _deleteAppDir() async {
    final appDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();

    if(appDir.existsSync()){
      appDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks,  it helps,  also do you know how can I read the amount of cache and file capacity which it occupied before delete process

Comment: Salam Ramin, it helps a lot.

Comment: @Ramin Hi, I try your code, it works... but when I check my apps size (data  and cache) in my hone setting, there are still data and cache... they didn't reduce the data and cache to 0 bytes... am I doing wrong?

Comment: @uyhaW Hi, I just checked that, and even if u clear cache & data using phone settings then reopen the app info it doesn't show 0 bytes. So I guess its normal.

Comment: where can I use this code? main?

Comment: Thanks for your time. But it doesn't making the data empty.

Comment: this throws: `(PathAccessException: Deletion failed, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B9862408-B34E-4B03-B7DE-728D201D8684/Library/Caches' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)) `. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Reading and Writing Files',
      home: FlutterDemo(storage: CounterStorage()),
    ),
  );
}

class CounterStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<int> readCounter() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();

      return int.parse(contents);
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      return 0;
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$counter');
  }
}

class FlutterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  final CounterStorage storage;

  FlutterDemo({Key key, @required this.storage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FlutterDemoState createState() => _FlutterDemoState();
}

class _FlutterDemoState extends State<FlutterDemo> {
  int _counter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
      setState(() {
        _counter = value;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<File> _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });

    // Write the variable as a string to the file.
    return widget.storage.writeCounter(_counter);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Reading and Writing Files')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Button tapped $_counter time${_counter == 1 ? '' : 's'}.',
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you can find very helpful document here:
https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/INDEX.md

Comment: Hi XAMT, it is not the solution,  what I want is to clear files,  and images because of cacheImages and other files which are in cache and app dir,  so I want to clear them inside app by users to increase the performance of app

Comment: import 'dart:io';

void main() {
    final dir = Directory(dirPath);
    dir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
}