# How to clear whole data of application in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, caching

Here I want to clear my app data on a button click.It needs to clear the  whole app data and cache memory of the app.

Hope you understand the question. Thanks.

I have some suggestions about it, but I'm not sure if this works. Here is some code:

```
var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);
```

Comment: I have the same problem with you, have you found the solution?

Comment: You might find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232893/how-to-delete-cache-and-app-dir-in-flutter), using the path provider.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Delete cache and app dir in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232893/how-to-delete-cache-and-app-dir-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

The following line you've provided is trying to clear the device's temporary folder.

```
var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);
```

But sometimes avoiding to clear the temp folder will do better and clearing the app's cache folder instead. Just like this:

```
var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path + '/<package_name>';
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);
```

Where `package_name` refers to the app's ***Bundle ID***.

There are also some packages that you could use like the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package as mentioned in the comments section. It allows us to access commonly used locations on the device’s filesystem. You can do something like this:

```
Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
    final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
      cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _deleteAppDir() async {
    final appDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();

    if(appDir.existsSync()){
      appDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
  }
```

Here is a [good reference](https://medium.com/kick-start-fluttering/saving-data-to-local-storage-in-flutter-e20d973d88fa) for path_provider.