# How to implement Flutter clear user app data and storage on logout

Tags: flutter

How to implement Flutter App clear user app data and storage on logout..
i want to clear everything (shared preferences, global variables, singletons, local storage, cache)
this should be equivalent to Android > settings > App > clear storage & clear cache..

Comment: You can use another option from [Shubhamhackz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64707995/7302514)

Answer (score 6):

first install [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

```dart
/// this will delete cache
Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
    final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
      cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
}

/// this will delete app's storage
Future<void> _deleteAppDir() async {
    final appDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();

    if(appDir.existsSync()){
      appDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
}
```

see the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59232994/10970839)

Answer (score 1):

you must use from [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to get your app TemporaryDirectory and app Directory
on the filesystem.

```dart
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    
    Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    
      if (tempDir.existsSync()) {
        tempDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
      }
    }
    
    Future<void> _deleteAppDir() async {
     Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      if (appDocDir.existsSync()) {
        appDocDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
      }
    }
```